# Acumatica Screen Customized But Not Listed in Project

Tags: c#, acumatica

I have a customization project that is affecting a screen that is not listed in its SCREENS section, and I cannot see any source code that would affect it, either.

NOTE: This is in Release 2021R2 Build 21.207.0045

Specifically, the screen ID: CR301000, the "Leads" screen, has a group for Contact info. In this group is an Account Name field.  The standard system looks like this:

[image: Stock Leads Screen]

When I publish my customization, the account name label changes to "Company Name" and it is not editable.

[image: With Customization]

However, my customization does not have anything in it for screen CR301000:

[image: SCREENS List]

And, the Graph for this is (I believe) LeadMaint -- and there is nothing in my CS project that deals with this Graph.

[image: Business Logic]

I am not sure where I can even go to look for this one... how can a screen be affected by a customization, if there is nothing in the customization that references it?

Answer (score 0):

I would check the Files section, from your screenshot I can see that two files are added. If those are .dlls they could be modifying that DAC field(changing the display name and setting it to disabled). If you haven't already I would check the Data Access section as well.

They wouldn't have to modify the LeadMaint graph they could be modifying the CRLead DAC.

Comment: The two files are the DLL for our source code and (strangely) its PDB file. But I have the source for that (written by my predecessor) and see nothing there. Nothing for LeadMaint or CRLead's DAC. What would I check in the Data Access section?

Answer (score 0):

In my case: the DAC extension of CR.Contact was being used by the LeadMaint graph. So, even though I didn't customize LeadMaint, the CR.Contact has the issue and that gets passed to whatever Graph uses it. (I learned something new...)

One of the reasons this was particularly thorny was that my predecessor used an unconventional naming for his extension:

```
CR_Contact_ExistingColumn
```

So none of my searches were finding it. Fortunately for me, he changed the display name from "Account" to "Company Name" and when I searched for that, I found my issue:

```
    [PXMassMergableField]
    [PXDBString(255, IsUnicode = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Company Name", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible, Enabled = false)]
    [PXPersonalDataField]
    [PXDefault(PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
```

I am not sure why he chose to disable it here, but changing it to Enabled = true fixed my problem.

Not sure anyone else will run into this strange set of issues, but in case you do, I hope this helps.